# How to do google webpage translate in a Java class

Tags: java

this is a follow-up question of mine.
Suppose now I have a URL :

http://www.baidu.com/s?bs=%B0%C2%B0%CD%C2%ED&f=8&wd=%B0%C2%B0%CD%C2%ED

and it work perfectly by inputting it in the text field of google translate and select from "Chinese" to English.

My question is ,suppose now I want to achieve this in Java,
I would like to adopt `Process q=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start +URL")`
approach to do this.
Could I achieve that by simply concatenating the Google translate URL and the webpage URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this api [google-api-translate](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to perform you http requests.